# using bzip gzip zip in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, bzip2

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# check if the user put a file name
if [ $# -gt 0 ]; then

    # check if the file is exist in the current directory
    if [ -f "$1" ]; then

        # check if the file is readable in the current directory
        if [ -r "$1" ]; then
            echo "File:$1"
            echo "$(wc -c <"$1")"

            # Note the following two lines
            comp=$(bzip2 -k $1)
            echo "$(wc -c <"$comp")"
        else
            echo "$1 is unreadable"
            exit
        fi
    else
        echo "$1 is not exist"
        exit
    fi
fi
```

Currently my problem is that I can compress the `$1` file into a `$1.c.bz2` file by bzip, but what if I come to capture the size of the compressed file. My code shows no such files.

Comment: Hi and welcome to unix.SE. OK, so first you need to clean up your code a little, there is at least one `fi` missing, it'll become obvious if you use proper indentation. The variable `**comp` is a problem, as your shell tries to use `*` as a globbing character. Please edit your question clarifying what you want to accomplish.

Comment: I'm assuming you wanna learn to shell script, but you perhaps should take a look at `atool`. It's a tool that abstracts many compressors (and uncompressors) and let's you streamline your command line experience dealing with compressing files, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I cleaned up the code for you:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

#check if the user put a file name
if [ $# -gt 0 ]; then
    #check if the file is exist in the current directory
    if [ -f "$1" ]; then
        #check if the file is readable in the current directory
        if [ -r "$1" ]; then
            echo "File:$1"
            echo "$(wc -c <"$1")"
            comp=$(bzip2 -k $1)
            echo "$(wc -c <"$comp")"
        else
            echo "$1 is unreadable"
            exit
        fi
    else
        echo "$1 is not exist"
        exit
    fi
fi
```

Note the additional `fi` in the second to last line.

Now, line 11 doesn't make all that much sense, as `bzip2 -k test.file` creates no output. Hence the variable `comp` is just empty.

A simple approach is to simply know that the extension is gonna be `.bz2`, so you could do for instance:

```
            echo "$(wc -c <"${1}.bz2")"
```

and not use the `comp` variable at all.

Comment: Instead of calling `echo (command substitution)`, why not just call the command? `wc -c <"${1}.bz2"`

Comment: @JeffSchaller I tried to do as little changes to his code as possible. Also, as I understand it, he perhaps wants to do some arithmetic on it later (calculate compression ratio)? But you're correct otherwise.

Comment: It's worth fixing the code to remove anti-patterns like this one, otherwise the OP isn't going to know it's wrong

Comment: @JeffSchaller if you guys think it's better to refactor his code like that, you can edit my post, but I think that'll be perhaps misleading, too, etc.

Answer (score 0):

`bzip2 -k` does not output anything, so running it in a command substitution and capturing the output in the `comp` variable would leave that variable empty.  This empty variable is your main issue.  It is also better, as in more efficient, to use `stat` than `wc -c` to get the size of a file at `stat` will just read the file size from the file's metadata without bothering to read all the data from the file.

You are also doing many unnecessary checks for file exitance and readability that distracts from the script.  These are checks that `bzip2` carries out anyway, and you can use that fact to avoid testing most of this yourself.

Suggestion:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

pathname=$1

if ! bzip2 -k "$pathname"; then
    printf 'There were issues compressing "%s"\n' "$pathname"
    echo 'See errors from bzip2 above'
    exit 1
fi >&2

size=$( stat -c %s "$pathname" )
csize=$( stat -c %s "$pathname.bz2" )

printf '"%s"\t%s --> %s\n' "$pathname" "$size" "$csize"
```

This script uses the exit status of `bzip2` to determine whether compressing the file went well or not.  If it fails, it outputs a diagnostic message to supplement the diagnostic message that `bzip2` already would have produced in the terminal.

Since you're using `-k` with `bzip2` to keep the uncompressed file around, the sizes of both files can be had after the `if` statement.  If you were to remove `-k` from the command, you naturally would have to fetch the uncompressed file's size before the `if` statement.

The way `stat` is used in the script assumes that the script is running on a Linux system.  The `stat` utility is non-standard and is implemented with other options on other systems.  On macOS or OpenBSD, for example, you would have to use `stat -f %z` in place of `stat -c %s`.

Testing:

```
$ ./script
bzip2: Can't open input file : No such file or directory.
There were issues compressing ""
See errors from bzip2 above
$ ./script nonexisting
bzip2: Can't open input file nonexisting: No such file or directory.
There were issues compressing "nonexisting"
See errors from bzip2 above
```

```
$ ./script file
"file"  600 --> 43
$ ./script file
bzip2: Output file file.bz2 already exists.
There were issues compressing "file"
See errors from bzip2 above
```

```
$ rm -f file.bz2
$ chmod u-r file
$ ./script file
bzip2: Can't open input file file: Permission denied.
There were issues compressing "file"
See errors from bzip2 above
```